# How to add class and diffrent paramter to every option in a dropdown in Zend Framework 2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

The title is clear , I want to add class and data-imagesrc for using a custom dropdown :

but this code wont do any good

```
        $this->add(array(
        'name'  =>  'require_course_id',
        'type'      =>  'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes'    =>  array(

        ),
        'options'       =>  array(
            'label'     =>  'prerequisite',
            'value_options' =>  array(array('label'=>'test','class'=>'test-class','data-imagesrc'=>'myimage')),//$this->getPrerequisite(),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect::renderOptions()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormSelect.php#L151) you will be able to see how each `<option>` is generated (and how the supplied configuration is merged to produce the final HTML string).

Provide the option tag's 'specification' as an array with an `attribute` key (just like the `Select` element itself).

```
$this->add(array(
    'name'       =>  'require_course_id',
    'type'       =>  'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'attributes' =>  array(),
    'options'       => array(
      'label'     => 'prerequisite',
      'value_options' =>  array(

        // For each option you require, provide it's own specification
        array(
          'label' => 'option 1 label',
          'value' => 'opt1value',
          'options' => array(
            // value and label can also be here
          ),
          'attributes' => array(
            // again value and label are ok here too
            'class' => 'test-class',
            'data-foo' => 'bar'
          ),
        ),
        // end option 1 specification

      ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Don't forget you're limited to a few attributes on a <option> tag, I don't believe 'class' is one of them. See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormSelect.php#L48. Correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar Very valid point; I did [check documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) - However there is no specific mention of this (it does say the 'global attributes' are allowed, `class` being one of them)

Comment: Which are in https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/AbstractHelper.php#L69 you're absolutely right! Thanks! Another thing by the way, is that `value_options -> options` config is for optgroups.

Answer (score 0):

**value_options** is used to set the options contained by the select element ([documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#select)). Just key/value, as it is what ZF2 Select renderer expects.

You'll need to create your own Helper in order to be able to draw it from your views. Extend it from **Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect** and override the **renderOptions** function.

Comment: "You'll need to create your own Helper" - Not true

Comment: @AlexP You're right. I've read the **renderOptions** too fast... Your answer is the good one.